# Added a goto statement; now I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: c, runtime-error, goto

I heard these were dangerous, too.. I used one to simply make having a 'valid input' check easy. Here's the code

```
char info_check = 'q';
while (info_check != 'y') { 
    Quadratic* eqn=newquadratic();
    printf("\nThe coefficients entered for '%s' are a=%g, b=%g and c=%g.\n", eqn->name_or_descrpt, eqn->a, eqn->b, eqn->c);
    printf("\nIs this information correct? (y/n): ");
  get_valid_option:
    scanf("%c", info_check);
    if (info_check != 'n' || info_check != 'y') {
        printf("\n\nInvalid choice! Please input either y or n: ");
        goto get_valid_option;
    }
}
```

Before what I thought would be an innocuous addition of a goto statement, the code ran fine. Weirdly, the error occurs slightly before the goto tag, and it doesn't print the second printf. What's going on?

Comment: Why would you use a goto and not another while loop? Check your y/n check logic, I don't think I'll be able to input 'y' or 'n' correctly.

Comment: `scanf("%c", &info_check);`

Comment: Also, think again about this condition: `if (info_check != 'n' || info_check != 'y')` - it is always true.

Comment: @AlexFarber Ah thanks - i don't often use single characters, treated it as a string!

Answer (score 2):

You missed `&` operator before `info_check` in `scanf`.

```
 scanf(" %c", &info_check);
```

And also place a space before `%c` specifier to eat newline character (`\n`) left over by previous `scanf`.